# Does a transformation that rotates a 3D shape around 2 axis simultaneously have any eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, rotations

I understand that the (sole) eigenvector of a transformation that rotates a 3D shape about an axis lies along that axis.

However, are there any eigenvectors in a transformation that rotates a shape around two (or more) axis simultaneously? Like in the motion of this sphere:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AV5JinSviE

My logic tells me no, since there would be no vector that remains on its span during this kind of rotation.

Comment: Indeed, for fixed rotation angles, there are such eigenvectors!

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52471/every-3d-rotation-must-have-an-axis